# Show image in uiimageview like an artist is drawing

Tags: ios, swift, gpuimage

I working on image processing. I am able to process image but client requirment is to show image like, its being draw by hand or something like a person is drawing(artist). please help me out.

Comment: why don't you add an imageView above the image you have processed and show a hand image on it ?

Comment: or may just combine two images your processed image and an image of artist's hand. ?

Comment: thanks for your kind reply developers. Client is not impressed this trick. I already discussed with him.

Comment: you are in need to add a layer i don't think so there will be another except above 2, When you find another good way please let me know so it may help me to increase mine knowledge

Comment: Sure sir. but still need doing R & D